# Least square methods: normal equation vs svd

Tags: numpy, linear-regression, least-squares, svd

I tried to write my own code for linear regression, following the normal equation that `beta = inv(X'X)X'Y`. However, the square error is much bigger than the `lstsq` function in `numpy.linalg`. Could anybody explain to me why SVD method(that lstsq uses) is more accurate than normal equation? Thank you

Comment: Please give a reproducible example.  There are several possible reasons, but without your data, we can only guess at the answer to your question (which I'll do anyway :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the matrix `X'X` for your data has a high [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number).  Trying to compute a numerical inverse of such a matrix can result in large errors.  It is usually a bad idea to explicitly compute an inverse matrix (see, for example, http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/ or http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9780898718027.ch14).

You can check the condition number using [`numpy.linalg.cond`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html).

Here's an example.  First create `X` and `Y`:

```
In [186]: X = np.random.randn(500, 30)

In [187]: Y = np.linspace(0, 1, len(X))
```

For this random `X`, the condition number is not large:

```
In [188]: np.linalg.cond(X.T.dot(X))
Out[188]: 2.4456380658308148
```

The normal equation and `lstsq` give the same result (according to [`numpy.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) when using that function's default arguments):

```
In [189]: betan = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(Y)

In [190]: betal, res, rnk, s = np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y)

In [191]: np.allclose(betan, betal)
Out[191]: True
```

Now tweak `X` by making two columns almost the same.  This makes `X'X` almost singular, and gives it a large condition number:

```
In [192]: X[:,0] = X[:,1] + 1e-8*np.random.randn(len(X))

In [193]: np.linalg.cond(X.T.dot(X))
Out[193]: 3954529794300611.5
```

Now the normal equation gives a different result than `lstsq`:

```
In [194]: betan = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(Y)

In [195]: betal, res, rnk, s = np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y)

In [196]: np.allclose(betan, betal)
Out[196]: False
```